# Putting a border on columns inside a division with row class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what my code looks like :

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 50px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="border col-md-5 px-5 py-5">
                Hi
            </div>
            <div class="border col-md-5 ">
                   Hi
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to put a border that covers the only the columns with col-md-5 class. I tried doing it by putting border (bootstrap) in div with row and container class . The border when I put border in class in row was near acceptable but the problem in that was it was covering extra space after the two columns.
Please help me out.

Comment: Did you try putting `border` on both columns?

Comment: Could you please provide a reproductible example?

Comment: @Zim Yes I did but that puts a border between the two columns as well which I dont want.

Comment: @Zim Is there anyway to put incomplete borders using css or bootstrap

Comment: @Zim HTML5 and bootstrap 4.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap borders are ["substractive"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/borders/#subtractive) as well so you can remove left/right side of the border on the columns...

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 50px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="border border-right-0 col-md-5 px-5 py-5"> Hi </div>
        <div class="border border-left-0 col-md-5 "> Hi </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/FC3sJALVVH